# How many ways can five dogs and/or cats be seated around a circular table? Consider two animals of the same type to be identical.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The answer is 8 and I don't understand how to come up with that. If it's linear the answer is n^r and for distinct objects circular permutation it's (n-1)!. And I know (n-1)^r is wrong...

Comment: Apply [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).  Since the number of seats is prime most the terms in the summation will be simple to calculate.  The answer being $\frac{1}{5}(2^5+2+2+2+2)=\frac{1}{5}(40)=8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All dogs: $1$ way

Four dogs and one cat: $1$ way

Three dogs and two cats: $2$ ways

Now repeat with dogs replaced by cats, and vice versa, so the total is $8$